# Adding custom entries to legend gradually

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to build up a plot gradually in multiple functions like this

### Example

```py
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def plot_on_axis(ax: plt.Axes, x: np.ndarray, y: np.ndarray, color, name) -> plt.Axes:
    ax.plot(x, y, color=color, label="orig")
    ax.plot(x, y + 0.2, "--", color=color, label="shifted")
    patch = mpatches.Patch(color=color, label=name)
    handles, labels = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()
    ax.legend(handles + [patch], labels + [name])
    return ax

def get_fig() -> plt.Figure:
    x1 = np.linspace(0, 3)
    y1 = np.sin(x1)

    x2 = np.linspace(0, 3)
    y2 = np.cos(x2)

    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.subplots()
    plot_on_axis(ax, x1, y1, "tab:blue", "sin")
    plot_on_axis(ax, x2, y2, "tab:orange", "cos")

    return fig

get_fig().show()
```

### Problem

However, this overwrites the `sin` entry in the legend so only `cos` shows up

[image: plot]

since the second call to `get_legend_handles_labels` only returns the four elements and not the added one (if it would return all, there would be duplicate entries for `sin`).

Is there a way to build up the legend in `plot_on_axis` or should the legend be handled in `get_fig`? Handling it in `plot_on_axis` seems much more elegant to me apart from this problem.

Alternatively, is there a better way to communicate grouping of the entries to the viewer of the plot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can return a list of `Artist`s instead of returning the `Axes` instance which you are not using anyway, then use those artists to create the custom legend in `get_fig`.

[image]

```
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from typing import List

def plot_on_axis(ax: plt.Axes, x: np.ndarray, y: np.ndarray, color, name) -> List[plt.Artist]:
    line1, = ax.plot(x, y, color=color, label="orig")
    line2, = ax.plot(x, y + 0.2, "--", color=color, label="shifted")
    patch = mpatches.Patch(color=color, label=name)
    return [line1, line2, patch]

def get_fig() -> plt.Figure:
    x1 = np.linspace(0, 3)
    y1 = np.sin(x1)

    x2 = np.linspace(0, 3)
    y2 = np.cos(x2)

    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.subplots()
    handles1 = plot_on_axis(ax, x1, y1, "tab:blue", "sin")
    handles2 = plot_on_axis(ax, x2, y2, "tab:orange", "cos")

    # Create the full legend.
    handles = handles1 + handles2
    labels = [handle.get_label() for handle in handles]
    ax.legend(handles, labels)

    return fig

get_fig().show()
```

Going for `ax.legend(handles, labels, ncol=2)` could be a nice way to further separate your two groups of data:

[image]